# Docker 'run' command to start apache

Tags: apache, docker

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 my-apache2:latest
```

Unable to find image 'my-apache2:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: repository my-apache2 not found: does not exist or no pull access.

P.S. It works with nginx(docker run -d -p 80:80 nginx:latest), I can see image using 'docker ps'

Answer (score 4):

Since a [search on DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/search/) returns nothing for `my-apache`, that would explain your error message.
[NGiNX does exists](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/) on DockerHub.

Yo would need to build locally an image named 'my-apache' in order for the `docker run` to proceed.

Or use the official [`apache httpd` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/).
Its instructions mention an 'my-apache', again by building it:

> Create a `Dockerfile` in your project
>
> ```
> FROM httpd:2.4
> COPY ./public-html/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
> ```
>
> Then, run the commands to build and run the Docker image:
>
> ```
> $ docker build -t my-apache2 .
> $ docker run -dit --name my-running-app -p 8080:80 my-apache2
> ```
>
> Visit http://localhost:8080 and you will see It works!

Answer (score 1):

Install the apache image using the following command

```
docker pull bitnami/apache
docker run --name apache -p 80:80 bitnami/apache:latest
```